# Properties of the set $ G = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z = \frac{i}{n}, n = 1,2,3... \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ G = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z = \frac{i}{n}, n = 1,2,3... \}$.

I want to investigate all interior points of $ G$. I reckon that there is no such point, since every open disk around with center in $a \in G$ with radius $r$ is not a subset of $G$.

Also, I want to decide all accumulation points to $G$. I'm not really getting hang of the definition of an accumulation point,

*"A point $c ∈ C$ is an accumulation point of $G$ if every open disk centered at $c$ contains a point of $G$ different from $c$."*

The limit $ n \to \infty $ yields $ 0 \in G$, and for every radius $r$ around $0$ we can find a point in $G$, if we make $n$ sufficiently big. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: You can suppress the $i$; It doesn't add anything!

Answer (score 1):

There are no interior points. If $a$ is an interior point, then there exists $r > 0$ such that $D(a, r) \subset G$,  notice that $G \subset \mathbb{Q}$ and $(a - r, a + r) \subset D(a, r)$,
as the irrationals are dense on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\zeta$ irrational such that $\zeta \in (a - r, a + r) \subset D(a, r) \subset G \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

0 is the only accumulation point of $G$. For all $r > 0$ $D(0, r) \cap G \neq \{\}$, notice that $[0, r) \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, as the $\mathbb{R}$ are archimedean, we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n \in [0, r) \subset D(0, r)$. Now choose $z \neq 0$ and $R = min\{|z - 1/n| \ | \ n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$, so $D(z, R/2)/\{z\} \cap G = \{\}$.